# Bash Getting pictures with limited properties

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to create a new simple bash scripting for bulk actions on pictures. I need only a few pictures, in this case, pictures greater than 2Mb and with a width greater than 2000px. But it seems my script doesn't work, I tried many variations but I always get the error **command not found in line 10**.

I think my problem resides in the if condition and maybe the String to Integer conversion...

I'm using identify (ImageMagick Packages) to get the parameters from every picture.

¿What I am doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */* ; do
        WIDTH="$(identify -format '%w' "$d")"
        WIDTH_LIMIT=$(($WIDTH+0))
        DATA="$(identify -format '%b' "$d")"
        SIZE=${DATA::-1}
        SIZE_LIMIT=$(($SIZE+0))
        if ["$WIDTH_LIMIT" -ge 2000] || ["$SIZE_LIMIT" -gt 2097152]
        then
        echo width in px: "$(($WIDTH+0))"px  ..  Size in bytes:  "$(($SIZE+0))" bytes
        fi

done
```

Comment: Why do you convert from string to integer in the first place, the shell doesn't care anyway? On which line do you get "command not found"?

Comment: Edited OP for the line subject. Well, it doesn't work neither if I try to compare without converting to integers, so I thought was about that, anyway. When I get the parameters from identify, I get for example "1920" , but size cames with a final B like... "21456121B" , that's why I'm removing the final B to just compare the numbers with 2097152. So I guess if it cames with a B, even removing that letter stills being a string. About the other one I'm not sure..

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the B, but the `$(( +0))` stuff is not required.

Comment: You need space after [ imo

Comment: Depending on the size of the file you may also get an MB at the end...

Comment: @Kiwy THANK YOU.  patrix by what I tested, getting the size parameter is displayed all in Bytes, so no worries I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is a either a binary or a bash integrated function.
`if` await the execution of something that will return 0 or 1.
In your case you try to execute the program: `["$WIDTH_LIMIT"` with argument `-ge` and `2000]` because your shell uses space to separate argument and `["$WIDTH_LIMIT"` is not a proper binary or bash command.
So you should always put space before and after `[` and `]` because they are regular command. You couldn't type `echo$UTY` your shell would not recognize it as a command in the `PATH`
I realize it's easy to remember the `[` syntax because it has a man page.
Try `man [` you'll see it's just an executable file or a built-in shell command (depending of your Unix/Linux flavour) with regular argument it need to have space after it.